# Array Print Particular Values asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a array like `Array arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }` and I want to print the values 1, 3, 4, and 6 like the below result:

[image]

I have tried it like this:

```
string println = "";
string len     = arr.Length - 1;

while (len >= 0)
{
    println = arr(len) - 1;
    len--;
}
```

I don't want to print it in hard code.

Any solutions?

Comment: What's the rule for selecting `1,3,4,6`?

Comment: And what is exactly your question? Does the logic work? Do you have trouble putting it on screen?

Comment: It is just a logic question don't have any rule

Comment: Then how would we know what the logic should be?

Comment: What would be the output if the array was `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }` or `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, The pattern seems to be to divide the array into groups of three, then print the first and last of that group. However, it isn't easy to say because he only gave one, small example.

Comment: I understand it seems to be like that, but please let OP clarify. He should check his homework assignment...

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int println;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    println = arr[i];
    i += 2;
    if (arr.Length > i)
        println = arr[i];
}
```